# transition animation not working in tailwindcss/react

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am a newbie learning React & Tailwind. I have a `Navbar` component which I have written like following,

```
const Navbar = () => {
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

    return (
        <>
            <nav className="flex justify-between items-center h-16 bg-white text-black relative shadow-md font-quicksand">
                <Link to='/' className='pl-8'>Project</Link>
                <div className="px-4 cursor-pointer md:hidden">
                    {/* <svg class="w-6 h-6" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"></path>
                    </svg> */}

                    <button 
                        type="button" 
                        className="bg-white rounded-md p-2 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500"
                        id="main-menu"
                        aria-haspopup="true"
                        onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}
                    >
                        <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                        <svg className="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </div>
                
                <div className="pr-8 md:block hidden">
                    <Link to='/' className='p-4 font-bold'>Home</Link>
                    <Link to='/menu' className='p-4 font-bold'>Menu</Link>
                    <Link to='/about' className='p-4 font-bold'>About</Link>
                    <Link to='/contact' className='p-4 font-bold'>Contact</Link>
                    <Link to='/login' className="p-4 font-bold text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500" role="menuitem">Log in</Link>
                    <Link to='/register' className="p-4 font-bold text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500" role="menuitem">Register</Link>
                </div>
            </nav>

            {showModal ? (
                <div className="absolute top-0 inset-x-0 p-2 transition duration-500 ease-in-out transform origin-top-right md:hidden">
                    <div className="rounded-lg shadow-md bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 overflow-hidden">
                        <div className="px-5 pt-4 flex items-center justify-between">
                            <div className="-mr-2">
                            <button 
                                type="button" 
                                className="bg-white rounded-md p-2 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500"
                                onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}
                            >
                                <span className="sr-only">Close main menu</span>
                                <svg className="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                                </svg>
                            </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="main-menu">
                            <div className="px-2 pt-2 pb-3 space-y-1" role="none">
                                <Link to='/' className="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50" role="menuitem">Home</Link>

                                <Link to='/menu' className="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50" role="menuitem">Menu</Link>

                                <Link to='/about' className="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50" role="menuitem">About</Link>

                                <Link to='/contact' className="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50" role="menuitem">Contact</Link>
                            </div>
                            <div role="none">
                                <Link to='/login' className="block w-full px-5 py-3 text-center font-medium text-indigo-600 bg-gray-50 hover:bg-gray-100" role="menuitem">
                                    Log in
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                            <div role="none">
                                <Link to='/register' className="block w-full px-5 py-3 text-center font-medium text-indigo-600 bg-gray-50 hover:bg-gray-100" role="menuitem">
                                Register
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ) : null}
        </>
    )
}
```

As you can see that when the screen got smaller the hamburger menu button will appear and when I click on that button it opens a modal with all the header components (The modal code copied from tailwind official components Hero components).

The problem is when that modal appears tailwind transition animation suppose to happen but it is not working. What am i doing wrong here?? Do i have to use the react hook `useEffect` somehow to make this work??

Any kind of answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify what transition animation should be happening?

Comment: In mobile view when someone click on the hamburger menu the div should open with a transition animation. If you go to this link https://tailwindui.com/components/marketing/sections/heroes and preview the first example with code and if you minimize the screen till the hamburger menu button comes and when you click on that menu button you can see the div opens with a transition animation.

Comment: Rather than simply showing/hiding the modal with state, you'll need to apply different styling for when the modal is hidden/visible so that the transition animation can occur. If you inspect the example you linked, you'll see different styles being applied to the div when the hamburger is clicked.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I manage to solve it using their transition library headless-ui https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui. It turns out that the transition was not getting built when i used raw html.